# What server do I need for big data (100GB of plain text)?

Tags: elasticsearch, server

What server hardware requirements do I need for 100GB of data (over 6 million records). I use it only for text search (not more then 3-4 words per search).

Which server is better for Elasticsearch?

How much CPU, RAM and disk space (HDD or SSD) do I need for 100GB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the link below gives some information about hardware requirements.
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/hardware.html

Some thumb rules:
one of the most important requirements is the RAM.. my suggestion is to choose a server with at least 16 GB ram.

HDD will work good for you